# js - calling properties of objects

Tags: javascript

If I were to make this object:

```
var usr = {
    function() {
        usr.name = prompt('What\'s your name?');
        // line 4
        usr.age = prompt('How old are you?');
        // line 6
        usr.clr = prompt('What\'s your favorite color?');
        // line 8
        usr.pref = prompt('Which strain of marijuana is your favorite?');
        // line 10
    }
```

, could I make this function:

```
function timedLog(p, d) {
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('Noted. You\'ve chosen: ' + usr.p + '.');
    }, d || 600)
};
```

?

My main concern is in calling the property: `usr.p`. I'm assuming the p will be replaced, so I changed my first input (`usr.+p+'etc...'`) to the aforementioned. Am I correct in assuming this, if I were to call the function as so:

```
timedLog(clr, 500);
```

? Is this an instance where the `this` keyword word come into play: `this.p`?

Comment: It is as simple as  `usr[p]()`

Comment: why are use it as a function?

Comment: No, `p` is not magically replaced by `clr`.

Comment: Just sain', `usr = { function() { …` is a syntax error unless you're using ES6

Comment: @Bergi It hasn't been giving me any problems storing values. The function, on the other hand, is bothering me.

Comment: @LiranBo, I'm trying not to have to repeat myself so much in the script.

Comment: Also, I'm obviously trying to slow down the pace of the machine so it doesn't fly through prompts and logs.